# Build a Visual Studio C++ project using the Command Line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, batch-file, cmd

I''ve written this batch script to build a Visual Studio C++ project using the Command Line:

```
pushd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\
VsDevCmd.bat
pushd F:\Master_Copy2\embedded\IFV-170\visualC12
Msbuild.exe DSP1_Emu.vcxproj
```

The script changes to C:\Program Files (x86)\ ... directory, runs the VsDevCmd.bat, and then don't complete the commands, and I don't know what's wrong.

Note: When I run these commands one by one in a Command window it runs properly and builds the project.

Edit: @roalz pointed out that I should use `Call` with the batch file VsDevCmd.bat, and this solved the problem.

Comment: Add a `pause` at the end of your bash file, it will pause the script before exit command window. Then you are able to see what's wrong with the commands.

Comment: It just runs the VsDevCmd.bat and doesn't continue the other commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the `call` batch command to call `VsDevCmd.bat` from inside your batch file.

"The CALL command will launch a new batch file context along with any specified parameters. When the end of the second batch file is reached (or if EXIT is used), control will return to just after the initial CALL statement."
Please see the [reference here](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)

Another suggestion is to enclose paths containing spaces inside double quotes, i.e.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\"